# Система модулей в 3D-приложении для мини-игр на C++

Tags: c++, boost, модули

Мы разрабатываем небольшую программу на С++, в которой я хотел бы реализовать систему модулей. Не важно, если они будут на Python, Lua или C++ (лично я предпочел бы C++ или Python).

Планируется, что система будет состоять из модулей, которые могли бы обращаться к уже существующим функциям этого приложения или определять свои собственные. В частности, модули должны быть в состоянии, например, вызывать или создавать элементы графического интерфейса пользователя. Приложение пишется с использованием ImGui, модуль должен быть в состоянии использовать этот графический интерфейс.

Было бы идеально, если бы система модулей могла быть установлена и удалена динамически. Я знаю, что это можно сделать на Python или Java, но как реализовать это в C++? Я задавался вопросом о необходимости boost.python, но я не смог найти, как это сделать.

Еще раз: Модуль должен иметь возможность создавать элементы интерфейса (в частности ImGui) в уже открытом окне 3D. В частности, я хотел бы иметь возможность добавлять приложения (миниигры), которые бы использовали функции приложения или создавали новые и при этом рисовали бы в окно этой большой программы.

**Вопрос: *Как реализовать динамические модульные системы приложений, на C++***

---

**Вот поправка/дополнение:**

*Я извиняюсь, в последнее время (16 лет) я по русски разговариваю мало, могу делать ошибки.*

Использую Линукс(Убунту). Думаю об реализации в виде  динамически-загрузгаемых  библиотек (.sо). Использовать хочу С++ (уже уверен).

Как я это задумываю, но я без понятия если это возможно:

Я нажму на кнопку ("миниигры"), приложение посмотрит какие модули (миниигры) есть в папке с модулями (например в */opt/app/minigames/*.sо*) и все мене их покажет в виде списка. Я выберу одну из них. Приложение должно (каждый модуль иметет один Interafce) загрузить этот модуль и спустить его, напр:

```
if(selected){
  interface::module modul = load(selected) ;
  modul.run();
}
```

Как я понимаю, для этого наверное надо написать SDK?

Намереваюсь, во время инициализации  модуля передать ему объект (context приложения через которое модуль может вызывать внутренние функции приложения) напр.:

```
context->gui->createAlertDialog(...);
```

Это так правильно? (Я английский язык не умею. Поэтому надеялся что мене тут помогут, раз уже везде говорят какие Русские замечательные хакеры :))

Comment: Перечитал 2 раза. Вопрос то где?

Comment: А зачем минус даешь? Я еще не научился спрашивать. Или ты думаешь что если дашь минус то поможешь? Неумеешь искать вопросы, не порть настроение...

Comment: начнем с того что **моего**  минуса здесь нет. Не надо воспринимать минуса на свой счет, это не более чем оценка вопроса/ответа с точки зрения конкретного участника. даже после правки вопрос не стал намного лучше. попробуй переписать его заново: пока это просто предыстория которая не нужна и вопрос. 3 минуса говорят об этом

Comment: Извиняюсь... :-/

Comment: ничего страшного, я тоже не так давно был *новичком*. если действительно хочешь получить ответ, то попробуй переосмыслить свой вопрос и задай более конкретно. удачи

Comment: [Вот тут разоблачение](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/614508/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8-segmentation-fault) *Комментарии там не для детей.*

Comment: [Вот разоблачение](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/614508/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8-segmentation-fault) *Комментарии там не для детей.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Денис, вопрос действительно задан ну очень скомкано. Как говорят, "без паллитры не разобрать")) Попробуйте его перефразировать лаконично, в стиле "есть/предполагаю + нужно". И только потом излагайте свои догадки решений/попытки решений.

> Вопрос: Как реализовать динамические модульные системы приложений, написанных на C++

Все, что вы желаете в своих желалках - называют **плагины**. Не важно на чем это реализовывать, хотя для вашей темы была бы неплоха связка `С++` + `Lua/LuaJIT`. Хотя вполне можно `С++` + `C++`, где вторая часть "оформляется" динамически-загружаемыми библиотеками (`*.dll` или `*.so`)

**Как реализовать систему плагинов?**

Не искал в сети, но уверен - материалов должно быть более чем достаточно. Далее ну очень кратко опишу основные вехи:

- основная программа должна уметь предоставлять свой API плагинам
- основная программа должна уметь загружать плагины
- основная программа должна уметь регистрировать дополнительный функционал, предоставляемый плагинами, если таковой плагином предоставляется

Все остальное - на усмотрение разработчика.

Comment: Путь намечен правильно. Да, дополнительный функционал плагин давать будет. Визуальный и системный. Визуальный в виде

    `context->gui->createAlertDialog(...);`
Системный в виде 

    `context->signal("name_of_module")->push<string>("hello");`
Или наподобие...

Comment: [Вот разоблачение](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/614508/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8-segmentation-fault)

_Комментарии там не для детей._