# Вызов функции из динамически-загружаемой библиотеки - segmentation fault

Tags: c++, dll, segmentation-fault

Язык: C++
ОС: Linux, ubuntu

Хочу в свою программу загрузить свой плагин в виде динамически-загружаемой  библиотеки(*.so). При попытке получаю **segmentation fault**.

*Вот код приложения:*

```
/* 
 * File:   Context.h
 * Author: denis
 *
 * Created on 13. ledna 2017, 23:33
 */

#ifndef CONTEXT_H
#define CONTEXT_H

#include <iostream>

namespace app {
    namespace context {

        class IO {
        public:

            IO() {

            }

            void printHello() {
                std::cout << "Hello worgld" << std::endl;
            }

            void print(const char* str) {
                std::cout << str << std::endl;
            }
        };
    }
}

#endif /* CONTEXT_H */
```

---

```
/* 
 * File:   Module.h
 * Author: denis
 *
 * Created on 13. ledna 2017, 23:43
 */

#ifndef MODULE_H
#define MODULE_H

#include "Context.h"


namespace app {

    class Module {
    public:

        Module() {
        }

        void SetContext(app::context::IO* context) {
            appContext = context;
        }

        virtual void Run() = 0;

    protected:
        app::context::IO* appContext;
    };
}

#endif /* MODULE_H */
```

---

```
/* 
 * File:   main.cpp
 * Author: denis
 *
 * Created on 13. ledna 2017, 23:32
 */

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include "include/sdk/Module.h"


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << "Start APP" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Enter number [1] to load module or type [2] to exit" << std::endl;
    int n = 0;
    app::context::IO* appContext = new app::context::IO();
    while (true) {
        std::cin >> n;
        std::cout << n << std::endl;
        switch (n) {
            case 1:
            {
                void* hndl = dlopen("libdl1.so", RTLD_NOW);
                if (hndl == NULL) {
                    std::cerr << dlerror() << std::endl;
                } else {
                    void* make = dlsym(hndl, "make");
                    app::Module* module = static_cast<app::Module*> (make);
                    module->SetContext(appContext);
                    module->Run();
                    dlclose(hndl);
                }
            }
                break;
            case 2:
                return 0;
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*Вот код библиотеки(плагин):*

```
/* 
 * File:   Santana.h
 * Author: denis
 *
 * Created on 14. ledna 2017, 1:16
 */

#ifndef SANTANA_H
#define SANTANA_H

#include "sdk/Module.h"

namespace bla {
    namespace bla {

        class Santana : public app::Module {
        public:

            Santana() {
            }

            void Run() {
                appContext->printHello();
                appContext->print("from dl1");
            }
        };
    }
}

#endif /* SANTANA_H */
```

---

```
/* 
 * File:   dl1.h
 * Author: denis
 *
 * Created on 13. ledna 2017, 23:40
 */

#ifndef DL1_H
#define DL1_H

#include "Santana.h"

extern app::Module* make();

#endif /* DL1_H */
```

---

```
/* 
 * File:   dl1.cpp
 * Author: denis
 *
 * Created on 13. ledna 2017, 23:40
 */

#include "sdk/Module.h"
#include "dl1.h"

app::Module* make() {
    return new bla::bla::Santana();
}
```

Где этот проблем? Дебаггера у меня нет.

Comment: "Дебаггера у меня нет." - значит, пора обзавестись.

Comment: Компьютер не тянет.

Comment: Глупости какие-то говорите. Попробуйте предоставить [mcve], желательно без использования множества разных файлов.

Comment: Это именно и есть тот код который я использую. Это _SANDBOX_ и он выплевывает **segmentation fault**. Это весь код, другого нет.

Comment: `весь` и `минимальный` это всё-таки разные понятия. Например, зачем все эти `namespace`, комментарии в шапке файлов, почему не ограничиться двумя файлами (программа, библиотека) для обеспечения демонстрации проблемы? Чем проще и понятнее будет описана Ваша задача - тем большее шансов, что Вам помогут с её решением.

Comment: _Это чтобы я понял. Я не такой уж и умный :-/_ И я не единственный новичок в C++. Вот добавил еще код в функцию майн: 
`void* make = dlsym(hndl, "make"); if (make == NULL) { std::cerr << dlerror() << std::endl; }`
получаю это: **libdl1.so: undefined symbol: make**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот разоблачение,

в файле библиотеки вместо:

```
app::Module* make() {
  return new bla::bla::Santana();
}
```

надо

```
extern "C" app::Module* make() {
  return new bla::bla::Santana();
}
```

а загрузку библиотеки зделать вместо:

```
void* make = dlsym(hndl, "make");
app::Module* module = static_cast<app::Module*> (make);
module->SetContext(appContext);
module->Run();
```

вот так

```
app::Module* (*make)() = reinterpret_cast<app::Module * (*)()>(dlsym(hndl, "make"));
if (make) {
  app::Module* module = make();
  module->SetContext(appContext);
  module->Run();
}
```

[А вот тут об этом написано подробней](https://kacperkolodziej.com/programming/introduction-to-programming-modular-applications-in-cpp.html)

:)